# grep extract number range

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I am grepping date `2019-09-XX` and `2019-10-XX` but somehow my grep not helping out, i am sure i am missing something here

```
  Last Password Change: 2019-10-30
  Last Password Change: 2017-02-07
  Last Password Change: 2019-10-29
  Last Password Change: 2019-11-03
  Last Password Change: 2019-10-31
  Last Password Change: 2018-09-27
  Last Password Change: 2018-09-27
  Last Password Change: 2019-06-27
```

I am doing following and it doesn't work

`grep "2019\-[09,10]\-" file`  also tried `grep "2019\-{09,10}\-" file`

Comment: `[]` matches one character of those it has inside, so your first regex would match `2019-,-` for example. `{}` determines how many characters must be matched for the previous matching atom, in your case `-`, so your second regex would match `2019-----------`. That's in extended regular expressions, though. Since you didn't supply `-E` or `-P`, then `{}` doesn't have special meaning. So, it matches literally `2019-{09,10}-`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the "alternation" regular expression token `|` to say "either this or that":

```
grep -E '2019-(09|10)-' file
```

See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) for some background on regular expression tokens and regex classes (basic, extended, etc).

Answer (score 2):

`grep` isn't good at handling numbers, it doesn't know how to compare them  arithmetically. For that, you may want to use something like awk or Perl. That's not very important here, since it's easy to just list out `09` and `10`, but if you had something like a range from 97 to 123 it would be much worse.

E.g. this would pick they year, month and day as numbers, and print out the lines where the day is between 27 and 31:

```
perl -ne 'print if /Last Password Change: ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/ && $3 >= 27 && $3 <= 31' < file
```

The regex is mostly like a grep ERE, the parenthesis capture the corresponding parts into the variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative:

```
grep -e "2019-10-.." -e "2019-09-.." file
```